# Animating circle to increase and decrease in size over a period of time - matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, graph, plot, data-visualization

I would like to create a simple visualization whereby the circle (country) will increase/decrease in size(Base on the variables) with respect to time.

How can it be done on matlab with my current dataset ? I would want each circle to represent a country and the size of the circle will be determined by the value in that particular year. *C1990 represents year 1990*

[image]

[image]
Can anyhow point me in the right direction or get me started with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here are two possible ways you could start, using `scatter` (note the AREA of the circles will be proportional to the values of `10*D`, not the radius or diameter)

```
close all
figure(1)
D=rand(10,10)
Cx=1:10;
Cy=Cx;
for i=1:length(D(:,2))
    scatter(Cx,Cy,(10*D(:,i)))
    drawnow
    pause(.1)
end
```

or plotting the circles manually, with RADIUS of the circle corresponding to `D`

```
figure(2)
D=rand(10,10)
Cx=1:10;
Cy=Cx;
phi=0:pi/100:2*pi;
for i=1:length(D(:,2))
    for k=1:length(Cx)
        r=D(k,i);
        plot(Cx(k)+r*cos(phi),Cy(k)+r*sin(phi))
        hold on
    end
    drawnow
    pause(.1)
    hold off
end
```

(You can have the area or radius of the circles be proportional to `D` in either case)

Comment: can i make an animation whereby the circle will increase / decrease over time ?

Comment: These do change over time, dependent on the values in `D`

Comment: I was trying to include my data into the second sample you have showed me but was having really weird results. `D=e(1:54, 1:21);` I have replaced this section of the code to call my data, 54 representing the 54 countries and 21 representing the years. 54x21 matrix. is it possible to reproduce something i have as above ?

Comment: `D(i,j)` should contain data about country `i` at time `j`, if that helps. You should be able to just replace my `D` with your data, and modify `Cx` and `Cy` so that they are vectors of the location of the centres of the circles, and there should be one for each country.